# Is it correct to use "....my such thinking.."?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

The following conversation took place with one of my friends while discussing about a theory.

Me: I am right (about some theory).

Friend: No, you are wrong.

Me: (After giving it a deeper thought) Well, I see your point. I may be wrong also. But the reason *behind my such thinking is that*......

As you see I used the structure "my such thinking" in the conversation. I felt uneasy using that structure and somehow it did not feel fluent or right.

Is this grammatically correct? Does an alternative like "The reason why I think like this is..." or "The reason of me thinking like this is..." sound better?

Comment: This "my such thinking" means "my thinking in a/some way is like this" is that.... It's rather peculiar though

Comment: Yeah @Flonne, that is the intention to express!

Answer (score 2):

**Idiomatic phrasing:**

- The reason for my thinking this way is etc.
- The reason behind my thinking this way is etc.
- The reason I think this or this way, etc.
- My thinking is etc.

Now, you are good to go.

"My such thinking" is not idiomatic in English.

The idiomatic phrasing is: My thinking. "Such thinking" refers to someone else's thinking and cannot be preceded by a possessive pronoun to be idiomatic. Also, in general, we tend not to use "such" forms of this phrasing in speech. We use other pronouns or objects: like this/ that or this/that way or this/that.

Answer (score 2):

"my such thinking is that" is not grammatically accurate. One wording that utilizes many of the same words, and I believe captures your meaning in a manner that is understandable, is "my thinking is such that..." Another alternative would be to simply remove the "such" from the phrase. Either way, you would be utilizing the same tone and dialect, but with more accurate grammatical structure.